# Can SQL Server database schema be generated from .NET classes

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-schema

I have some old code which didn't use database. Now can database schema be auto-generated from existing classes? I know this seems reverse than usual DB to class generation.

But it would be good if there is some easy way to do so.

Comment: You could create a new Entity Framework 4 "model-first" model and transfer your .NET classes into there and then generate SQL DDL statement out of that - but it would require quite a bit of extra work (setting all the database properties and defining FK-relationships and so on)

Comment: @marc_s: Would ER Code First allow him to go straight from his POCOs to a DB schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with a little reflection you could generate some rough table creation scripts, and even stored procedures to support INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETES (if you wished).

Unless there is an **exact** one-to-one mapping, you will need to clean up those scripts by hand.

EDIT: to elaborate on this further (in conjunction with @TomTom's answer)

Things that will be difficult/impossible to infer automatically:

- default column values
- computed columns (if any)
- varchar sizes
- NULL/NOT NULL columns
- indexes

Things that you could do automatically with a bunch of work (but better to do by hand, IMO):

- primary key assignment
- foreign key relationships
- relationships

Comment: yea, any starting point to use reflection for this ? or do i have to write code. well, i know it wouldnt be a clean job and may not be possible even without annotations, but just in case if there is some tool to do it.

Comment: @Munish - you could write a simple method that takes a Type as an argument, enumerates all public properties, and dumps out create scripts to a text file. If you haven't used reflection, it's really not hard. Start with a Type object and the interface on it is pretty object (methods like "GetProperties()" will get you the members you would need.

Answer (score 2):

It is not. Or, only ins a very stupid way. Without additional annotations .NET contains a lot less information than a db schema. Conditions, checks arem issing. Data types are missing, too. And how you think such code would deduct what indices to have? Heck, even finding out the primary key of a class / table is not possible.

Inheritance is another topic.

You can generate a schema as a start, but you can not really generate a database that is production ready without annotating the classes heavily.

Comment: +1 - unless the database was filled with nulls and varchar(max) columns, there is plenty of work to do by hand (as I noted in my answer).

Comment: actually i could have done with some starting point, may not be production ready and may not have PK or condition checks etc. just default names and data types of columns, if at all possible

Comment: If he refactored the classes into LINQ to SQL entities or ADO.NET EDM entities he could use attributes to specify the database types and some constraints. Then the database could be created programmatically. However it probably wouldn't save any time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS2010, you may want to look at Code-First development using Entity Framework, with your classes inheriting from DbContext. ScottGu has a good blog entry [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) on how to do that.